# how would I use a for loop in my hive query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am running a hive query in sparksql that goes like this:

```
select
    GREATEST( 
            CASE WHEN x1 = 2 then y1+3 else -1,
            case when x2 = 2 then y2+3 else -1,
            case when xe = 2 then y2+3 else -1,
            .....
            case when x100 = 2 then y100+3 else -1
            )
            as greatest_sum
        from table
```

I need to loop through about 100 columns for each row and get the greatest value after applying the case statements.
I have 100 case statements. I'm looking for a way to do this without repetition over 100 lines. how would I do this?

I have made the case statements simple in this example but I have each case spanning over 15 lines in my code which makes repetition not the best way to go.

Comment: well, all I can provide is to declare a temptable and variable that when in loop it insert the result row into the temptable and use that temptable to process further work.

Comment: but  doing loop in sql is the worst thing ever, don't do it unless it is last resort...

Comment: you can write shell script to call a sql again and again in a loop. shell script - `for flag in 1 2;
do
  hive -hivevar flag=$flag -f new_qry.hql
done`. So compare and calculate greatest and insert the val in a table and then compare with the next val.